# FBSDKShareDialog shareContent doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, sharing, fbsdk

When I am trying to use FBSDK share dialog with shareContent of type video, FBSDKShareDialog appears empty on iPhone 5 and 5s devices, running iOS 10. 
Other (newer) devices seem to work well, and it seems to me that it worked sometime ago on all devices.

Maybe someone can clarify why this can happen?

I didn't find duplicates, as similar questions were referred to older iOS releases or a bit different issues.

[image: Code]

[image: Result]

Comment: Are you sure that the video & content properties are initailized successfully?

Comment: @BencePattogato, why should it fail if it works on other devices? The object exists after initialization.

Comment: Was just a debugging tip, maybe sg. is different in the bundle.